# Travis-CI build doesn't start at all on a pull request

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

After making some changes to my `.travis.yml` file, I find after pushing to my branch that neither my commit nor the pull request associated with my branch are getting checked by a Travis CI build:

[image]

Instead, I should be seeing a green or red notation beside the commit number, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The changes I made to my `.travis.yml` file made it no longer parse as valid YAML.

I pasted the contents of my `.travis.yml` file into the [Travis WebLint](http://lint.travis-ci.org/) utility to check, and that was the problem.

After I pushed a correction, Travis-CI started to do builds for my commits again.

Answer (score 4):

To investigate the problem with your build, on Travis CI you may go to *Requests* tab. It may be hidden, so just change in URL `/pull_requests` into `/requests` to show all the attempts for the build. E.g.

[image: Travis CI requests tab - build - missing config]

Most common problem is misconfiguration or missing `.travis.yml`. Even when it's saying *missing config*, the message is misleading, as there could be a syntax error in the YAML file.

To check for the syntax, run (if you've `travis` command):

```
travis lint
```

otherwise check your configuration on-line at [Travis WebLint](https://lint.travis-ci.org/).

If the file exists and there is no syntax error, check if you've pushed your branch correctly and you're not [whitelisting/blacklisting your `branches`](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/).